# Change Multiple div font colors using one Colorpicker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change both divs using the same color picker. I'd like to be able to use a class to specify which div should be assigned a color by a color picker.

This is the jsfiddle that shows what I'm trying to resolve: http://jsfiddle.net/z0cfu4a4/

Here is the code:

```js
$(".basic").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) {
        $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
        document.getElementById("basic").style.color = color.toHexString();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js"></script>
<link href="http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class="basic"/>



<p id="basic" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 3em; font-weight:bold;">
TARGET TEXT
</p>

<p id="basic" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 3em; font-weight:bold;">
TARGET TEXT
</p>
```

Comment: I also cant get the spectrum css/js to run :(

Comment: This is another jsfiddle that shows what I'm trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/z0cfu4a4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z0cfu4a4/3/   You are using the same id for both elements which is not valid, i.e. id's are unique, the point is to loop through elements with the same class.

Comment: OK, so how would you write that?

Comment: Didn't you see the fiddle?

Comment: Aha! Got it! This works now.

Comment: Aha, ok, what if I wanted to have a second colorpicker that changed the background color of a third div? Using the same idea where you called a Class name?

Comment: Then you can do it with an id, like before.

Comment: yes, but this div will repeat into several divs, so I think I need to use a Class, no?

Comment: also, currently the last code snippit targeted font color, how would you specify background-color in JS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z0cfu4a4/15/

Comment: Ah, almost. I'm trying to make the first two 'color' (font-color), and then I'm trying to make the last one background-color -- and also using a Class name so I can repeat it in other divs.

Comment: It's pretty obvious what to change, change backgroundColor to color inside the first for loop.

Comment: Awesome, yes, now I've got it.